# Override maven release goal defined in a parent POM from command-line

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a need to run alternative release goals instead of the default `deploy` as part of `release:perform`. Our company-wide parent POM defines something like the below under `pluginManagement`:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
        <goals>deploy</goals>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I am trying to override this using `-Dgoals` option, but maven is ignoring this and running `deploy`. I tried also setting `-DuseReleaseProfile=false` and also changing `-DreleaseProfiles` and none of them seem to make any impact. I can't change the project POM as I would need to do this part of our CI framework and for arbitrary projects. I am able to override for a test project that doesn't use the above parent POM, so seems like the issue is with overriding what comes from parent POM. Are there other options I can make use of here?

Update:

This is the exact command-line: `mvn -X -e -nsu release:perform -Dgoals=install -DlocalCheckout=true -Darguments="-DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none -DskipTests"`

I ran with `mvnDebug` instead of `mvn` and put a breakpoint in `org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.createGoals()`. When the breakpoint was hit I checked the value of `goals`:

```
main[1] stop in org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.createGoals
Deferring breakpoint org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.createGoals.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
main[1] run
> Set deferred breakpoint org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.createGoals

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.createGoals(), line=220 bci=0

main[1] print this.goals
 this.goals = "deploy"
main[1] print java.lang.System.getProperty("goals")
 java.lang.System.getProperty("goals") = "install"
```

By the time `[createGoals][1]` is called, `goals` must have been already injected, but I am not familiar with maven code to know from where.

Comment: Usually, command line arguments should override POM configuration. Could you post the exact command you used?

Comment: @JFMeier This is the exact command-line: `mvn -X -e -nsu release:perform -Dgoals=install -DlocalCheckout=true -Darguments="-DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none -DskipTests"`